# Open Operation Timeout - WCF web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I've create a web service.  After being up for a period of time, I eventually get the follow error: **"The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."**

I'm unsure why I'm getting this error since I've set the open timeout to about 2 hours.  I'm new to WCF web services and web services in general.  Is there any red flags with the configuration I've shown below?

.NET version: 4.0

**Client-side configuration:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="SecurityServiceDev" receiveTimeout="02:00:00" openTimeout="02:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxConnections="1000" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" maxMessagesToLog="300" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://XXX.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityServiceDev" contract="SecurityProxy.ISecurityService" name="SecurityService" />
</client>
```

**Web Service Configuration:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TMS.DAL.Common.Security.BAL.SecurityService" behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://XXX.svc"
                 name="SecurityService"
                 binding="netTcpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="Binding"
                 contract="TMS.DAL.Common.Security.BAL.ISecurityService"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding"
                receiveTimeout="02:00:00"
                openTimeout="02:00:00"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                maxConnections="1000"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client/>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="61200000" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000"
      maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The only configuration inside the code is the following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class SecurityService : ISecurityService
```

**Service Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISecurityService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool IsUserInRole(String userName, String roleName);

    [OperationContract]
    bool DoesUserHavePermission(String userName, String permissionName);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> GetUsersInRole(String roleName);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> GetRolesForUser(String userName);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> GetPermissionsForUser(String userName);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> GetPermissionsForRole(String roleName);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> GetRolesForApplication(String appName);

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetListValuesForRoleAndList")] 
    List<String> GetListValues(String roleName, String listNames);

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetListValuesForRolesAndList")] 
    List<String> GetListValues(List<String> roleNames, List<String> listNames);

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetListValuesForAppUserList")] 
    List<String> GetListValues(String appName, String userName, List<String> listNames);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> GetListsForUser(String userName);

    [OperationContract]
    bool RoleExists(String roleName);

    [OperationContract]
    bool ExternalUserExists(String userName, String password);
```

Comment: Are you closing the client's proxy after your done making calls?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using and can you show us the service contract?

Comment: @Tim  The web application is making continuous calls to the web service.  I don't have any code that closes the client's proxy.  I was hoping connection were being code automatically.  The web apps are making quite a few calls to the WS throughout which I know may be a design mistake.  How do I go about closing the client's proxy?

Comment: I think Tim is right - essentially you are blowing the session throttle and further requests are queuing up and then timing out. Where do you create the client proxy?

Comment: Consider using sendTimeout attribute as well along with the other timeout attributes

Comment: @Richard I use VS 2010. I right-click Service Reference and point to the web service.   Address is set to http://XYZ.svc.  It brings up the SecurityService and I click ok.  It generates a service reference.  Does that answer your question?  How do I go about closing the clients proxy?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes but somewhere you create an instance of SecurityServiceClient (I assume thats what the name of the generated class is) or you use a ChannelFactory directly and call CreateChannel - where do you do that?

Comment: Ok, I've done some research.  @Richard I was doing it in the constructor but now I'm creating an instance of SecurityServiceClient before every call to the web service.  I realize now that I must close the client proxy in the code.  I followed this approach: http://timrayburn.net/blog/idisposable-wcf-and-hole-in-the-middle/

Answer (score 2):

Each page gets created anew for the request and then discarded - NetTcpBinding is inherently sessionful which means it keeps resources around until the client says they no longer need them or the client goes away for, in your case, 2 hours as you have set the receiveTimeout to 2 hours.

As you don't call `Close` WCF thinks the session is still alive and so will throttle the requests from the new pages until old sessions start timing out. The .NET 4 default session throttle is fairly high (100 x number of cores) and you have set it yourself at 1000 so you will not see this problem until the processing ahs been running some time. In some ways the default session throttle in .NET 3.5 was better at 10 as it became very obvious very quickly if you were in the situation you are in

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,af6e6325-2e30-42e3-acb9-57e1363fa51e.aspx) about sessions a while back